# IPv6 для работы с прокси

Tags: proxy, squid

Я использую DigitalOcean. У меня 16 адресов IPv6. Мне удается просто создать прокси (я использую 3proxy и squid), но даже когда я использую эти настройки, я всегда получаю IPv4, когда я захожу на сайты для проверки IP. Как мне решить эту проблему?

```
nserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
nscache 65536
timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60

daemon

# http (s)
#auth none
auth strong
users user1: CL: user1
allow * * * *
proxy -6 -n -a -p3128 -i142.93.207.142 -e2604:a880:400:d1::7dc:8000
proxy -6 -n -a -p1001 -i142.93.207.142 -e2604:a880:400:d1::7dc:8001

# socks
#auth none
auth strong
users user1: CL: user1
allow * * * *
socks -6 -p1002 -i142.93.207.142 -e2604:a880:400:d1::7dc:8002
socks -6 -p1003 -i142.93.207.142 -e2604:a880:400:d1::7dc:8003
```

Comment: Давайте начнём с очевидного: вы уверены, что ваши сайты для проверки IP поддерживают IPv6?)

Comment: @andreymal поддерживает